# Trying to draw dashed border for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, cashapelayer

I'm trying to draw a dashed bottom border to `UITableViewCells` with the following code:

```
func addDashedBottomBorder(to cell: UITableViewCell) {
    let width = CGFloat(2.0)
    let dashedBorderLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let frameSize = cell.frame.size
    let shapeRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: frameSize.height, width: frameSize.width*2, height: 1) 

    dashedBorderLayer.bounds = shapeRect
    dashedBorderLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: frameSize.height)
    dashedBorderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    dashedBorderLayer.lineWidth = width
    dashedBorderLayer.lineDashPattern = [9, 6]
    dashedBorderLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: shapeRect, cornerRadius: 5).cgPath

    cell.layer.addSublayer(dashedBorderLayer)
}
```

However, I'm getting a strange solid line behind my dashed line as can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM3Rs.jpg

I've already set `tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear` in `viewDidLoad`

Any ideas why I'm getting that solid line behind the dashed one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
func addDashedBottomBorder(to cell: UITableViewCell) {

    let color = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

    let shapeLayer:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let frameSize = cell.frame.size
    let shapeRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frameSize.width, height: 0)

    shapeLayer.bounds = shapeRect
    shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: frameSize.width/2, y: frameSize.height)
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = color
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
    shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [9,6]
    shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: shapeRect.height, width: shapeRect.width, height: 0), cornerRadius: 0).cgPath

    cell.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Please tell, from where we should call this function. And what if path varies for each cell

Answer (score 2):

if you have write

> tableView.separatorStyle = .None

Still, yo are getting a solid line below dassed pattern then 100% it is not tableview separator. It is something else

> check your Table background colour, When you clear separator color, a
>   small space remains between cell. If you cell background color
>   different color from table background color, it visible like a
>   separator.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

In Swift

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .None
```

Comment: it will not make any difference. The problem is with layer logic

Answer (score 1):

The line you are showing with your donted line is default `TableViewCell` seperator, you can remove it directly from the interface builder instead of writing any code.

In interface builder select your `TableView` and in the `Attributes Insepector` Set `Separator` property to `None`.

[image]