# Trying to add dashed border separator in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cashapelayer

Using this example I am trying to add a dashed border to my UITableView.

[Trying to draw dashed border for UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298946/trying-to-draw-dashed-border-for-uitableviewcell)

But it does not work. It shows nothing.

```
func addDashedBottomBorder(to cell: UITableViewCell) {
    let color = UIColor.black.cgColor

    let shapeLayer:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let frameSize = cell.frame.size
    let shapeRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frameSize.width, height: 0)

    shapeLayer.bounds = shapeRect
    shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: frameSize.width/2, y: frameSize.height)
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = color
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
    shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [9,6]
    shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: shapeRect.height, width: shapeRect.width, height: 0), cornerRadius: 0).cgPath

    cell.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

I am using this method in `cellForRowAt` but it shows me nothing and in `viewDidLoad`, `table.separatorStyle = .none`.

Comment: isn't shapeLayer  height always zero as shapeRect declared with zero height?

Comment: just increase height to 10 but nothing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the below 2 lines of your code:

```
    shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
    shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: shapeRect.height, width: shapeRect.width, height: 0), cornerRadius: 0).cgPath
```

`kCALineJoinRound` is making upper and lower dash lines but they are overlapping due to the `height` of `UIBezierPath` is 0. So, Updated your code as:

```
    shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: shapeRect.height, width: shapeRect.width, height: 1), cornerRadius: 0).cgPath
```

It will hide the lower line and you will get the desired result.

**Best Solution:**

Rather than hiding lower dash line, you can correct it by providing just `lineDashPhase` to your `CAShapeLayer`, as:

```
    shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
    shapeLayer.lineDashPhase = 3.0 // Add "lineDashPhase" property to CAShapeLayer
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [9,6]
    shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: shapeRect.height, width: shapeRect.width, height: 0), cornerRadius: 0).cgPath
```

**Received line is:**

[image]

Comment: bro i just update the lines which u provide but still same its showing nothing

Comment: Did you see a black line or no line at all?

Comment: there is no line at line only blank space

Comment: @Jhony, try adding `heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath` delegate method.

Comment: heightForRowAt  solve my problem finally Thank u so much

Comment: bro it work perfectly but in iphone se i show just simple line why?